# Why is the interaction term defined by multiplying the IVs?

Tags: regression, interaction

I am trying to get a deeper mathematical understanding of regression, beyond just applying it and interpreting the output. Can somebody provide me with the mathematical rationale for why interaction terms in a regression equation are defined by the product of the involved independent variables? I assume it has to do with calculating the model sum of squares, and the portion of variance in the IV which cannot be independently attributed to the IV alone (as a main effect), but I do not understand the underlying mathemathics.

Comment: The `[mathematical-statistics]` tag is inappropriate for this question. Note also that interactions don't really have anything specifically to do with SEM.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an approach. Consider this model: $$Y = \beta_0+\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon.$$ Now, the marginal effect of $X_1$ on $Y$ ($Y$'s derivative w.r.t $X_1$) is simply $\beta_1$. I can replace $\beta_1$ with anything, that will be $X_1$'s effect (assuming it doesn't contain $X_1$): $$Y = \beta_0+ \left(<\text{what we write here will be $X_1$'s effect}>\right) X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon.$$

In the first case, we wrote $\beta_1$, which is a constant, so the effect of $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$. That's why there is no interaction. We want to introduce an interaction, i.e., that $X_1$'s effect depends on $X_2$? Let's write something there which depends on $X_2$! For simplicity, be linear here as well, i.e., assume that the dependence itself is also linear: $$Y = \beta_0+\left(\beta_1 + \gamma_{12}X_2\right) X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon.$$ That is, the effect of $X_1$ will be $\beta_1 + \gamma_{12}X_2$, so we have the interaction as we aimed for: the *effect* of $X_1$ depends on the *value* of $X_2$. (In this simplest case, linearly.)

Now we expand it: $$\beta_0+\beta_1 X_1 + \gamma_{12}X_2 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon,$$ and voilá, here we have the product.

Comment: Thanks, it is starting to make sense! One thing that is not clear is why we use γ instead of β to mark the coefficient term of the interaction. Is it just to make them visually distinct for purposes of illustration, or is there some deeper reason mathematically?

Comment: "Is it just to make them visually distinct" Absolutely. You could have used $\beta$ as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Just for clarification: Is taking their product the only possible way to make X1 and X2 dependent on each other? Would it also make sense mathematically to take their quotient, or X1 raised to the power of X2? What would be the disadvantage of doing so? As far as I understand, the model would still be linear in the coefficients, would it not? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @BálintL.Tóth No, see my updated answer, you can write anything there, for instance $\gamma_{12} X_2^2 X_1$ is also perfectly fine. And yes, $\gamma_{12}X_1^{X_2}$ is also possible, although in that case the interaction will no longer be symmetrical. You have to be careful though what can be estimated with OLS, e.g., $X_2^{\gamma_{12}}X_1$ won't work, at least with OLS.

Comment: This is a very good, intuitive answer that (in my view) is far more clear than any of the linked answers in the other post asking the same question.

Comment: @Parseltongue Thank you very much, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to think of this in terms of categorical predictors. Let $Y$ = sweetness of a cup of a coffee measured in some way. Let $X_1$ = $1$ if you stirred the coffee, and $0$ if you did not stir the coffee. Let $X_2$ = $1$ if you added sugar to the coffee, and $0$ if you did not add sugar to the coffee.

Now suppose you posit the model :
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$$

What does $\beta_1$ represent? It represents the effect that stirring the coffee has on its sweetness. But that seems strange by itself. Of course, the effect of stirring on coffee depends on whether or not sugar was added. So the betas, as it stands, don't really capture the relationship as it exists in reality. Let's modify our model as such:

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3(X_1 \cdot X_2) + \epsilon$$

So we've added an interaction term. What is the effect of this modification? Well, $\beta_3(X_1 \cdot X_2)$ will be $0$ if either $X_1$ or $X_2$ are $0$. It only affects calculation of $Y$ if their product is $1$, i.e. $X_1 = X_2 = 1$, i.e. you both added sugar and stirred the coffee. So we've allowed for an extra effect on sweetness when both predictors take value $1$ ("the whole is more than the sum of its parts"), and we've done so by taking advantage of properties of the *product* of two binary variables.

This is why it's defined this way. Interactions between continuous variables are also defined by a product. Try to think of an example with two continuous predictors, and what happens to their product given high/low values of each.

Comment: Another great intuitive explanation.